# Some questions about ssl

Tags: ssl, security

I have a couple questions about SSL.

1. What happens if someone tampers or changes the encrypted data? There are many ways in which the data being transferred can be tampered, so though the encrypted data will not make any sense to the tamperer, what would happen if he just tampers it? How would I handle such scenarios?
2. What will happen if a webpage is requested by a browser which does not support SSL? Or the client accessing the website is actually some kind of malware?

I am pretty new to SSL so maybe my questions are very trivial but I don't have answers to them.

Comment: Upvoted pointless unexplained downvote.

Comment: Yeah but the point is there can be tools if not browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The packets including the URL itself is encrypted. Modify the bytes will make the packet invalid. As far as I know it is not accepted by the server then.
2. If a client browser don't support your SSL protocol it can't access the website. The client get a "Insecured Request Denied Error".

SSL is to establish a secured connection. Any software, including malware, that support the protocol can start a connection. The SSL protocol "just" encrypt the communication so the packets can't be inspected outside. So your software itself need to be protected against any attacks anyway.

Comment: So do ssl certificates handle the problem of malwares?

Comment: Not really. SSL is a protocol that only encrypt the data through transportation. If you have any trojan or other malware on client side the "Houston has a problem".

Answer (score 1):

1. The tampering will be detected on arrival and the connection automatically dropped, probably resulting in a dialog box to the browser user.
2. I'm not aware of any browser that doesn't support SSL. Such a thing would be singularly useless.